# How to add 'Done' button on the number keypad using react-native

Tags: react-native

i am using number-pad keyboard in react-native, i want to hide the keyboard when click on done button,for that i want to add done button above the keyboard, is there any possibility like IOS apps to hide the keyboard, Any help much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show "DONE" button above "number-pad" keyboard? using react-native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995950/how-to-show-done-button-above-number-pad-keyboard-using-react-native)

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can add a 'done' button to the keyboard using the prop returnKeyType.

E.g: `returnKeyType={ 'done' }`

More info here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype

Comment: I think, it's not possible in keyboardType="number-pad", returnkeyType='done' not working in keyboardType="number-pad"

Answer (score 10):

**returnKeyLabel** - What is the text of the button.

**onSubmitEditing** - Click Action. `Keyboard.dismiss` here to dismiss the keyboard.

```
<TextInput 
  returnKeyLabel='Done' 
  returnKeyType='done' 
  onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss} />
```

Comment: not working to me, I need done button above keyboard, not done action while I am using multiline

Answer (score 8):

Using `React Native v.63` in 2021

- If you just use the `returnKeyType='done'` it will automatically **hide the keyboard**
- Notice you could also use your own function with `onSubmitEditing={() => yourFunctionNameHere()}`

This worked for me =>

```
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.textBox}
                  maxLength={5}
                  placeholder="Enter Zip Code"
                  placeholderTextColor={'#6D7376'}
                  autoCompleteType="postal-code"
                  keyboardType="number-pad"
                  returnKeyType="done"
                  onChangeText={text => setZip(text)}
                  onSubmitEditing={() => yourFunctionNameHere()}
                />
```

here is the direct documentation
https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#returnkeytype

[image: screenshot here]
[image]

Comment: It works indeed but if we want "next" instead, it doesn't work...

Comment: There's a workaround if you want to put a custom label on your button. Just use [InputAccessoryView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/inputaccessoryview)

Answer (score 0):

Natively the UITextField doesn't support returnKeyboardType when keyboardType="number-pad"

Custom keyboard development can help you.