# how to show "DONE" button above "number-pad" keyboard? using react-native

Tags: react-native

can any one tell me that how to show "DONE" button above "number-pad" keyboard, that i want like this

[image]

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 19):

From React Native v0.47+ you can use TextInput's prop **returnKeyType="done"** in combination with **keyboardType="number-pad"**.

Answer (score 1):

we can use returnKeyType.

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.codeInput}
  placeholder="Enter Code"
  value={this.state.pinCode}
  keyboardType="number-pad"
  returnKeyType={ 'done' }
  onChangeText={(code) => this.setState({pinCode: code})} />
```

Comment: returnkeyType not avialable in keyboardType="number-pad", that can be used in emai, But in number keyboard keyType 'return' is not there.

Comment: Can You use Like This 
              <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    keyboardType='numbers-and-punctuation'
                    placeholder='Numbers & Punctuation'
                    returnKeyType='done'
                />

Comment: it working ok, but it not like above image, i want to add done button as like above image

Comment: @ Pramod Mg  there any solution for this issue

Comment: @HussianShaik u can do it with a simple Style if you would like else by default i dint find a method to do the done

Comment: can you please send the sample code code if possible

Answer (score 0):

## Also **checkout** an updated answer on here

[How to add 'Done' button on the number keypad using react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821030/how-to-add-done-button-on-the-number-keypad-using-react-native/65761104#65761104)

[image]